# clonning with http show master branch while clonning with ssh don't work

Tags: git, ssh, https

clonning with http show master branch while clonning with ssh don't  work

git clone git@test.com/test.git

```
> Cloning into 'test'... remote: Counting objects: 19609, done. remote:
> Compressing objects: 100% (6451/6451), done. remote: Total 19609
> (delta 12576), reused 18124 (delta 11553) Receiving objects: 100%
> (19609/19609), 5.38 MiB | 6.17 MiB/s, done. Resolving deltas: 100%
> (12576/12576), done. Checking connectivity... done. warning: remote
> HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
```

Comment: does anybody knows whats actually wrong\